# Does act of creation violate tawhid?

Tags: contradiction

If, in the beginning, there was nothing but God, how could God have created anything, unless God created it from himself? And if God did make creation from himself, wouldn’t that violate the oneness and unity of God by dividing God between Creator and creation?

Comment: The question is unclear. What does preceding creation have to do with being separate from them?

Comment: Changed the question and added more details

Comment: Seems the question assumes that creation needs to be from "something", almost like converting X to Y. That's less creation and more transformation.

Comment: Yes because in the beginning there was no "nothing" to create anything from but infinite god. So god must have created everything from himself

Answer (score 0):

The standard Islamic position is that God's power of creation includes the ability to create from no prior material. So, God doesn't need something to be there so that He can transform into something else, neither does He need to use His divine essence (assuming that were even logically coherent as a possibility!). He has the ability to bring things into existence without any prior thing before them.

It is important to differentiate this from the concept of "causation from nothing" which is also sometimes called "creation from nothing." Causation from nothing is impossible because something coming to exist without a cause is absurd.

However, the creation from nothing we mean does include a cause (God), but this cause (God) simply has the ability to brings things into existence without prior materials.

So, in the beginning, only God existed. Then, He created the universe without prior materials, outside Himself, and that is within His power.

The purview of God's power is defined as the ability to make any logically coherent possibility come true. A logical coherent possibility is anything that is not self-contradictory or essentially impossible (like a square circle or a rock heavier than God can lift). Since "a creation outside God" has no logical self-contradiction, it is possible. Since it is possible, it is within God's power to bring into existence.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Then God is not infinite. Clearly there are limits to his existence and outside of him there is nothing.

Comment: @SalmanSheikh No such thing as "outside God" before He created the creation. God is eternal, not infinite in terms of place. As everyone knows, God isn't in creation.

Comment: Your first statement can only be true if god is infinite. The question isn't what everybody knows, rather does it make sense ?

Comment: @SalmanSheikh It makes sense if nothing exists other than God. Then, there's no concept of outside God until God creates things outside Himself. Has nothing to do with being infinite.

Comment: Yes, according to you, there's a concept outside of God. And that concept is called nothing. Does God coexist alongside nothing, or rather is he infinite in every conceivable way, leaving simply no room for something to exist that isn't him(for example, nothing)

Comment: @SalmanSheikh "Infinite" is simply not an attribute for God I have heard used in Islamic circles. "according to you, there's a concept outside of God. And that concept is called nothing" This entire statement makes no sense. Nothing is the lack of things, not a concept that exists outside God... Concepts don't have a place, to be inside or outside.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the grammatical mistake appreciate it. I meant you clearly appreciate that there can be nothing outside of God, not even nothing. It's not possible for God to coexist with something he's not therefore he's infinite. Then you contradict yourself and say he's finite. But if he's infinite in all his attributes how can he be finite in size ?

Comment: @SalmanSheikh "there can be nothing outside of God, not even nothing" this sentence is nonsense. When we say there was nothing outside God, that just means there was no thing outside God until God created a thing outside Him. He neither needs a place to create nor material to create from. He simply has the power to create things outside Himself.

Comment: Why is it nonsense ? I use nothing in two different senses. But you haven't answered my question but just reaffirmed what you said in the beginning. This is getting pointless.